# Oraclize inspecting contract queries

Tags: cleos

in reading through this guide: https://docs.provable.xyz/#eos-advanced-topics I'm attempting to see the queries issued to the contract:

```
cleos -u https://kylin.eos.dfuse.io/ get actions oraclizeex1a -1 -4 --console
```

but I get the following error:

> Error 3110003: Missing History API Plugin Ensure that you have
>   eosio::history_api_plugin added to your node's configuration! Error
>   Details: History API plugin is not enabled

how is this supposed to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this error message states that the node you're using doesn't have the History API plugin enabled... I found a couple that does have this plugin enabled:
1. https://api-kylin.eoslaomao.com
2. https://api-kylin.eosasia.one

Also - note that there's no such account on Kylin (`oraclizeex1a`), so you'll have to find the right contract account as well...

Comment: you're correct, the account is wrong.  I can't raise support from Oraclize.  I'll open a new issue regarding that, and thanks for pointing out the issue of the node